# Optaplanner: Custom move and multithreading - all solver threads stuck in waiting forever after custom move list is exhausted

Tags: multithreading, wait, deadlock, move, optaplanner

I am doing a simple time slot (planning entity) -> team (planning var) assignment task. All work fine while using only one thread. Also multithreading works fine if one custom move I have is not involved, but after it's used the solver gets stuck forever with no message. All the custom moves are created before every STEP. Full assert doesn't say anything. It looks like deadlock for me. I am using optaplanner 8.25.0.Final with Java 17

This is the move factory:

```
package pl.medaxtrans.pre.solver;

import org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.Move;
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.factory.MoveListFactory;
import pl.medaxtrans.common.domain.Team;
import pl.medaxtrans.pre.domain.HalfHourTimeslot;
import pl.medaxtrans.pre.domain.ShiftsSolution;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class FarSlotChangeMoveFactory implements MoveListFactory<ShiftsSolution> {

    private static Predicate<HalfHourTimeslot> equalTime(HalfHourTimeslot slot2) {
        return slot -> slot.compareTo(slot2) == 0;
    }

    private static Predicate<HalfHourTimeslot> sameDayAndTeam(DayOfWeek day, Team team) {
        return slot -> slot.getDayOfWeek().equals(day) && slot.getTeam().equals(team);
    }

    @Override
    public List<? extends Move<ShiftsSolution>> createMoveList(ShiftsSolution solution) {
        List<FarSlotChangeMove> moves = new ArrayList<>();
        List<HalfHourTimeslot> slots = solution.getSlots();
        List<Team> teams = solution.getTeams();
        for (Team fromTeam : teams) {
            for (Team toTeam : teams) {
                if (fromTeam != toTeam) {
                    for (DayOfWeek day : DayOfWeek.values()) {
                        List<HalfHourTimeslot> fromTeamSlots = slots.stream().filter(sameDayAndTeam(day, fromTeam)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        List<HalfHourTimeslot> toTeamSlots = slots.stream().filter(sameDayAndTeam(day, toTeam)).collect(Collectors.toList());

                        Optional<HalfHourTimeslot> fromMinOpt = fromTeamSlots.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
                        Optional<HalfHourTimeslot> fromMaxOpt = fromTeamSlots.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
                        Optional<HalfHourTimeslot> toMaxOpt = toTeamSlots.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
                        Optional<HalfHourTimeslot> toMinOpt = toTeamSlots.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder());

                        if (fromMinOpt.isPresent() && fromMaxOpt.isPresent() && toMaxOpt.isPresent() && toMinOpt.isPresent())
                        {
                            HalfHourTimeslot fromMin = fromMinOpt.get();
                            HalfHourTimeslot fromMax = fromMaxOpt.get();
                            HalfHourTimeslot toMax = toMaxOpt.get();
                            HalfHourTimeslot toMin = toMinOpt.get();

                            if (toMin.compareTo(fromMin) < 0 && toMax.compareTo(fromMin) > 0 && toTeamSlots.stream().noneMatch(equalTime(fromMin)))
                            {
                                moves.add(new FarSlotChangeMove(fromMin, toTeam));
                            }

                            if (toMin.compareTo(fromMax) < 0 && toMax.compareTo(fromMax) > 0 && toTeamSlots.stream().noneMatch(equalTime(fromMax)))
                            {
                                moves.add(new FarSlotChangeMove(fromMax, toTeam));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return moves;
    }
}
```

And this is the problematic move:

```
package pl.medaxtrans.pre.solver;

import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.director.ScoreDirector;
import org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.AbstractMove;
import pl.medaxtrans.common.domain.Team;
import pl.medaxtrans.pre.domain.HalfHourTimeslot;
import pl.medaxtrans.pre.domain.ShiftsSolution;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Objects;

public class FarSlotChangeMove extends AbstractMove<ShiftsSolution> {

    private final HalfHourTimeslot slot;
    private final Team toTeam;

    private final Team fromTeam;

    public FarSlotChangeMove(HalfHourTimeslot slot, Team toTeam) {
        this.slot = slot;
        this.toTeam = toTeam;
        this.fromTeam = slot.getTeam();
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractMove<ShiftsSolution> createUndoMove(ScoreDirector<ShiftsSolution> scoreDirector) {
        return new FarSlotChangeMove(slot, fromTeam);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doMoveOnGenuineVariables(ScoreDirector<ShiftsSolution> scoreDirector) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(slot, "team");
        slot.setTeam(toTeam);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(slot, "team");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMoveDoable(ScoreDirector<ShiftsSolution> scoreDirector) {
        // we don't check overlaps here, because it is already checked by the move factory
        return !toTeam.equals(fromTeam);
    }

    @Override
    public FarSlotChangeMove rebase(ScoreDirector<ShiftsSolution> destinationScoreDirector) {
        return new FarSlotChangeMove(destinationScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(slot), destinationScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(toTeam));
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> getPlanningEntities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(slot);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> getPlanningValues() {
        return Collections.singletonList(toTeam);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return slot + " {" + fromTeam + "->" + toTeam + "}";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final FarSlotChangeMove other = (FarSlotChangeMove) o;
        return Objects.equals(fromTeam, other.fromTeam) &&
                Objects.equals(toTeam, other.toTeam) &&
                Objects.equals(slot, other.slot);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(slot, toTeam, fromTeam);
    }
}
```

After using this move and right after this trace message (after cachedMoveList is empty):

```
2022-09-14 20:13:28,568 [main] TRACE     Created cachedMoveList: size (0), moveSelector (MoveListFactory(class pl.medaxtrans.pre.solver.FarSlotChangeMoveFactory)).
```

All solver threads get blocked in "WAIT" mode and they never stop waiting. What are they waiting for and what did I do wrong? This is expected that this move list ends at some point and I want solver to stop solving then. Why is it not happening as opposed to single thread solving? On the other hand while solving with one thread only I get:

```
                    No doable selected move at step index ... Terminating phase early.
```

And it ends. I want the exact same behavior with multithreading.

Comment: I think there are 2 bugs. One in your move factory and one in OptaPlanner. OptaPlanner should not get stuck forever if there are no moves; it should fail gracefully instead. That's the OptaPlanner bug. But what I think is more important is something that looks like a bug in your move factory. There should always be some moves to be done! So either make sure your factory always produces some moves, or if under some conditions it is unable to do so, use a `<unionMoveSelector>` and mix your custom move factory with a built-in move selector, e.g. `<changeMoveSelector>`.

Comment: This sounds like a bug indeed. The move threads apparently can't handle the decideMove() calls exiting abnormally. Please [create a jira](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER) with an isolated reproducer.

Comment: Thanks @yurloc. I used your second tip with the unionMoveSelector. However I am not convinced whether this abnormal termination should be treated as a bug in custom move list factory. I know beforehand that some of the moves cause hard constraints to be broken, so I filter them out in the factory. When the score is getting better there are more and more moves like this so finally the whole list gets empty. But from what you are saying there should always be some moves. Why is it so? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet speaking of the optaplanner bug I will create the ticket in the upcoming days. I need to recreate it first in some more basic example

Comment: Thanks, [fixed in 8.29.0 Final release](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2811)